# ThreeJS material.setValues is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm starting out using three.js and I'm getting an error in `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();` where

> `this.setValues is not a function`

in this block of threejs' source code:

**three.js**

```
THREE.MeshLambertMaterial = function ( parameters ) {

    THREE.Material.call( this );

    this.type = 'MeshLambertMaterial';

    this.color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ); // diffuse

    this.map = null;

    this.lightMap = null;
    this.lightMapIntensity = 1.0;

    this.aoMap = null;
    this.aoMapIntensity = 1.0;

    this.emissive = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
    this.emissiveIntensity = 1.0;
    this.emissiveMap = null;

    this.specularMap = null;

    this.alphaMap = null;

    this.envMap = null;
    this.combine = THREE.MultiplyOperation;
    this.reflectivity = 1;
    this.refractionRatio = 0.98;

    this.wireframe = false;
    this.wireframeLinewidth = 1;
    this.wireframeLinecap = 'round';
    this.wireframeLinejoin = 'round';

    this.skinning = false;
    this.morphTargets = false;
    this.morphNormals = false;

--> this.setValues( parameters );

};
```

Coming from this call in my javascript:

**graphics.js**

```
var sphereMaterial = THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
                {color: 0x55B663});
```

Does anyone have any experience with this error and/or know what could be causing it?

Comment: What version of three.js? setValues is on the parent Material class and has been for a very long time. I doubt the MeshLambertMaterial class is the problem.

Comment: @2pha I'm honestly not sure, I dug around the README and docs/ and cant find a version number anywhere. I downloaded it off their site about a week ago though

Comment: @2pha I'm on chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps anything

Comment: @2pha I'm getting a similar error with the renderer class' ```setClearColorHex``` function when I remove the LambertMaterial --> ```renderer.setClearColorHex is not a function```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the keyword **new** when creating a new Material or Geometry:

```
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
```

Side note: you can see the version number of your release by typing in the console `THREE.REVISION` or just looking at the top inside the file `three.js` / `three.min.js`.

Comment: nice one, I missed that

Comment: Yeah I saw your comment and was surprised, but your guess is already correct. Its not always three.js´s fault :-)